# Twilio Multi-Dial and Multi-Gather

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

## Backstory

Twilio lets us multi-dial pretty easily with

```
<dial>
   <number>...</number>
   <number>...</number>
   <number>...</number>
</dial>
```

but this has the behavior of "first connection wins".  That is, the first number to pickup (connect) gets the connection while all other numbers get cancelled/dropped.

## Problem

The documented problem with this is when a number in that list answers on the first ring, such as voicemail for an off-network cell phone, the connection is won by an automated system, defeating the intent of the multi-dial.

## The Question

How can we do a multi-dial that includes a gather, such that the first person to pickup *and dial a digit or two* wins the call, so that automated pick-ups don't win the call?

Answer (score 0):

I have personally found SimRing an extremely unpleasant feature for the dialed parties.

There isn't a way to use the SimRing feature of the `<Number>` [noun](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number). You will need to build out your own logic, to place outbound calls using the [REST API Calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) and make sure your Account has necessary Calls Per Second (CPS) to simultaneous initiate the number of planned calls without queueing delay.

You will then need to programmatically keep track of which party answers the call and positively responds to the requested feedback (to confirm they are a human), then cancel all other call legs (some will be in the process of pressing a button while others may not have yet answered).

I would be best if you can come up with another way to handle your use case.

Comment: That's what we were afraid of.  Thanks for responding.